# jQuery filter, check all checkbox values

Tags: jquery, filter

With help from @Deadpool in another question, I managed to put together a method of filtering out div results based on check box values.

HTML

```
            <div id="search_section">

                <h3>Candidate Experience</h3>

                <div class="search_box_exp">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="3year" value="3yearexp"> 3+ Years <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="5year" value="5yearexp"> 5+ Years <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="7year" value="7yearexp"> 7+ Years <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="10year" value="10yearexp"> 10+ Years <br>
                </div>

                <h3><br>Candidate Salary</h3>

                <div class="search_box_sal">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="3039" value="s29"> less than £29,999<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="3039" value="s3039"> £30,000 - £39,999 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="4059" value="s4059"> £40,000 - £59,999 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="6079" value="s6079"> £60,000 - £79,999 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="80plus" value="s80plus"> £80,000 + <br>
                </div>
            </div>


<br>
<br>
<div style="display: block;" class="talent_result_wrapper" data-experience="5yearexp" data-salary="s29">
      <div class="talent_result_header">
        <span class="talent_result_head">ID: </span>100006
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Resides:  </strong>Redditch</li>
          <li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£29000</li>
          <li><strong>Experience:  </strong>2 Years </li>
          <li><strong>Industy:  </strong>10</li>
          <li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>10</li>
      </ul></div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="display: block;" class="talent_result_wrapper" data-experience="10yearexp" data-salary="s6079">
      <div class="talent_result_header">
        <span class="talent_result_head">ID: </span>100007
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Resides:  </strong>London</li>
          <li><strong>Salary Required:  </strong>£67000</li>
          <li><strong>Experience:  </strong>4 Years </li>
          <li><strong>Industy:  </strong>24</li>
          <li><strong>Specialism:  </strong>24</li>
      </ul></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".search_box_exp input[type=checkbox]").click( function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
    } else {
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").hide();
        $("div[data-experience='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    }

    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    if(n === 0){
        $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
    }

});

$(function () {
  $(".search_box_sal input[type=checkbox]").click( function(e){
                if($(this).val().length == 0){
                $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
                    } else {
                        $(".talent_result_wrapper").hide();
                        $("div[data-salary='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
                    }

            var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
            if(n === 0){
            $(".talent_result_wrapper").show();
            }
    })
});
```

I have this fiddle up to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MCam435/qnvxK/4/

What I'm trying to do now, is to get it to look at more than one checkbox value, for example, if I click 5 years and 10 years, it should show both divs. Similarly with the salary, so it should look at the experience and salary area. Currently it's only looking at the last checked box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
// finding all inputs of type="checkbox" within the '#search_section' element,
// binding a function to the 'change' event
$('#search_section input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){

    // caching the 'this' node (since we're using it more than once):
    var self = this;

    // finding all div elements with a 'data-experience' attribute that's
    // equal to the value of the un/checked checkbox
    // showing/hiding that/those element(s) depending on whether checkbox
    // is checked or not
    $('div[data-experience="' + self.value + '"]').toggle(self.checked);

// triggering the change event to show/hide the relevant div elements
// based on the initial state of the checkboxes
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qnvxK/10/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind I was being a prat. Thank you very much for this, works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You want to change this line

`$("div[data-experience='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();`

to access all the checkboxes states.

```
$(".search_box_exp input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $("div[data-experience='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    }
});
```

Same with the other checkbox list.

```
$(".search_box_sal input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $("div[data-experience='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works just as well as David's answer but I've had to mark his as the answer as he added comments and a JSFiddle link. Again, thank you though, and I would upvote if I had the rep to do so!